# Pacemaker does not boot service after node switch

Tags: ubuntu, cluster, pacemaker, corosync

I am using two virtual Ubuntu servers (latest long-term) and both have equal configuration, and are running Squid services and pcs pacemaker corosync. I have two nodes `Squid01` and `Squid02` with one virtual IP.

The problem: When I start both servers `Squid02` usually is the one doing all work by starting Squid proxy service but `Squid01` proxy service automatically disables itself and becomes inactive so then I shut down the `Squid02` server and switch between server nodes happens, but `Squid02` proxy service still is inactive and you have to start it manually.

**It does not see a stopped service**

I need to achieve that when the switch happens the inactive service becomes active OR both services are working all the time.

I have used [this](https://itnshare.blogspot.com/2015/01/installing-squid-proxy-in-clustered.html) example to create cluster

But only one difference is that I don't have Squid from `apt-get`, but I have created it manually with config

```
[Unit]
Description=Squid Web Proxy.
[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/usr/local/squid/var/run/squid.pid
ExecStart=/usr/local/squid/sbin/squid
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I skipped firewall part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by editing service file like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Squid Proxy.
[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/usr/local/squid/var/run/squid.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/squid/sbin/squid –z 
ExecStart=/usr/local/squid/sbin/squid 
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And updating Pacemaker to the newest version where the bug is fixed.

This solution was used in Ubuntu Linux, Currently I am using CentOS which has the latest Squid and Pacemaker so these problems are not existant anymore.